# Evaluating an answer to an unsatisfactory question

Tags: support, review, questions, low-quality-posts

I have for the first time tried to look at answers flagged as Low Quality; some of them are 'too short'.  In many cases I have considered, the question itself has been too short - a single one-line question.  If I bring up the selection box for reasons to delete the post, I rarely find a near match to the problem.

But my question is whether there is any way I can address the short question *itself* without going back to the homepage and looking it up.

I am a beginner with the system, so forgive this low-level question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I bring up the selection box for reasons, I rarely find a near match to the problem.

You don't *have* to use one of the canned comments; you can go to the Q&A page itself and leave a more applicable comment. (Or use one of the comments and modify it, if that's easier.) There's a handy 'link' to the post:

[image]

From there, you can also do something about the question (comment, edit, or flag/vote to close, whatever action is appropriate).

Note that shortness does not match 1-1 with being low quality; sometimes a short problem description or problem solution is all that it takes.

Comment: Thank you for this:  I’ll try your advice.  My own question seems to be regarded as very low level.   Is there any way I can find out why, and improve?

Comment: It was rather unclear what you were asking (not entirely your fault, since you're new) and SHOUTING is something which isn't really appreciated anywhere. The current version of the question is fine and I've upvoted it.