# Insufficient options in the low-quality review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

I believe that [Add downvote option to Low Quality Review Queue list of potential actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228738/add-downvote-option-to-low-quality-review-queue-list-of-potential-actions) needs to be revisited.

When using the low-quality post review queue, there are three options for answers: looks ok, edit, or delete. More than once, I've run across an answer is most certainly not "ok" - it is not good as it is and it definitely is low-quality. However, I am unable to edit it because I don't have the knowledge necessary to fill in the missing details. However, deleting seems wrong because, even though it doesn't meet the community quality standards, it's minimally helpful and deleting would do a disservice.

It is possible to leave a comment and down-vote from the review queue, but that's not always the best option. Sometimes, the post is already at -3 or more downvotes and downvoting more feels like piling on. Especially if it's a newer user, that feels very unwelcoming. Leaving a comment is a good option, but there's still no way to progress onward without selecting a wrong choice in the options. It feels wrong to downvote and/or comment with how to improve while also saying that the post "looks good".

I'm not sure exactly what the solution looks like. One option is the one presented in the linked question. Another would be to remove the options entirely and let the reviewer use the tools visible in the post (voting, editing, commenting, deleting) in-line, and then saying either "done" (if any actions were taken) or "not low quality" (if no actions are needed), where the "done" option would be disabled unless at least one action was taken.

Comment: But... this is not late answers or first posts. The purpose of the queue is to delete problematic posts. If you feel a post is bad but not delete-worthy - just downvote and skip

Comment: Halfway related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364255/369802. The OP there was also struggling with having to vote 'Looks OK' while the post wasn't 'OK'. I wrote an answer there suggesting to rename 'looks ok' to something like 'don't delete', which might be a third option to consider here as well.

Comment: @Tomerikoo The purpose is not to delete problematic posts. It's to _find and improve_ low-quality posts. Sometimes, it's been downvoted sufficiently, but the remaining action is to leave a comment for the poster on how to improve. As a moderator, if I push delete, that deletes the post with no other review, so that's not an option for me, but the fact that all moderator options are always binding is another problem. Skipping also feels wrong since I've taken actions. The actions in the sidebar and what I do just don't line up.

Comment: "it is not good as it is" - what does this mean?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It needs some kind of improvement, but the reviewer is unable to improve it. There are plenty of posts where I can read and tell that they don't meet the standard for what a good answer (or good question) is, but I don't have the prerequisite knowledge or experience to improve it myself.

Comment: *"Skipping also feels wrong since I've taken actions."* - You've taken actions that doesn't *improve* or *delete* the post so it shouldn't count as an action in the queue.

Comment: I view the options as "Shouldn't be deleted/closed", "Fix the post so it doesn't need to be deleted/closed", "Should be closed" and "Should be deleted". As a person who struggles a bit with taking things too literally, I have to make these adjustments all the time. That doesn't mean I wouldn't welcome a more precise wording of the various options though.

Comment: @ColleenV I think I'm the same way. Although if I struggle with that, I wonder if non-native English speakers also struggle with that kind of ambiguity and lack of precision in what the options mean. Just changing the wording could be sufficient.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I disagree. A comment with information that can help the poster (or someone else knowledgeable in the area) understand what needs to be done can help to improve the post. It's indirect action, but still an action.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I don't doubt for a second that non-native English speakers have trouble with the wording of certain things. We've got the questions on ELL to prove it (somewhere, please don't make me find them ;))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have more options for low-quality reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364255/can-we-have-more-options-for-low-quality-reviews)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating an answer to an unsatisfactory question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334720/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239692/282094

Comment: The choices are usually enough: delete, don't, or don't know; if you need more choices click on the link. Don't use deletion to *save* yourself 1 rep on an answer that shouldn't be deleted, but you *could* downvote - also use the link to access the Flag Dialog if it's spam or R/A.